# Variables in python loop

Tags: python, loops

How can i save data from each variable (salary & cost_car), after each run (it can for example be 3 people), so i can later use it for calculation.

```
nr = int(input("How many people: "))
total = 0

for i in range(1, nr+1, 1):
    print("For person ",i)
    salary = float(input("Salary per month : "))
    cost_car = float(input("Cost per month for car: "))
```

Comment: Have you learned about using lists yet? That's the tool you'd use (or potentially, a dictionary instead).

Comment: If you just mean to store the data while the script is running: a dictionary or list would work just fine.  If you want to save information long-term: you can look into local JSON file's or databases. Here is some information on dictionaries vs lists: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-list-and-dictionary-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
nr = int(input("How many people: "))
    total = 0
    people = []

    for i in range(1, nr+1, 1):
       print("For person ",i)
       salary = float(input("Salary per month : "))
       cost_car = float(input("Cost per month for car: "))
       people.append({'salary':salary, 'cost_car': cost_car})
   
  # compute salary
  total_salary = 0
  for person in people:
     total_salary += person.salary
  print('total salary is {}'.format(total_salary))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several data structures you can use to store data in your running program. Since your persons are numbered in your example, it makes sense to store the info for each person in a list. You can represent the info for each person as a simple dictionary, where the keys represent names of different information:

```
nr = int(input("How many people: "))
total = 0

persons_info = []

for i in range(1, nr+1, 1):
    print("For person ",i)
    salary = float(input("Salary per month : "))
    cost_car = float(input("Cost per month for car: "))
    
    info = {salary: salary, cost_car: cost_car} # the info of person i
    persons_info.append(info) # store it in the list of all persons info
```

You can then after the for loop retrieve the info for person n by doing: `persons_info[n-1]` (since list indexes start at 0), which will give you a dictionary of their information.

A better approach could be to represent each person with a `Person` object, i.e. an instance of some `Person` class that represents the information associated with a real person. This way, you can also include and implement different operations that you would want to perform in the `Person` class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, salary, cost_car):
        self.salary = salary
        self.cost_car = cost_car
    
    def getNetWorth(self):
        return self.salary + self.cost_car

nr = int(input("How many people: "))
total = 0

persons = []

for i in range(1, nr+1, 1):
    print("For person ",i)
    salary = float(input("Salary per month : "))
    cost_car = float(input("Cost per month for car: "))
    
    person = Person(salary, cost_car) # an object representing person i
    persons.append(info) # store it in the list of all person objects
```

And again you can retrieve the info for person n by doing: `persons_info[n-1]` (since list indexes start at 0), which will give you a object representing their information.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a list to store the data and the data in the list can be used for later computation.

```
nr = int(input("How many people: "))
total = 0
salarylist = [ ]
costcarlist = [ ]

for i in range(1, nr+1):
    print("For person ",i)
    salary = float(input("Salary per month: "))
    salarylist.append(salary)
    cost_car = float(input("Cost per month for car: "))
    costcarlist.append(cost_car)
```